# TO create unit test of following Ruby code

Tags: ruby, sqlite, unit-testing, csv, minitest

I am working on a problem to create the unit test program of a Ruby program.

The Ruby code is as follows:

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'CSV'

class Task8
  def initialize
      @f=File.open('C:/Users/aroraku/Desktop/boc-adap_td-agent.log-2.log','r')
      # @f1=CSV.open('C:/Users/aroraku/Desktop/task8_data.csv','wb')
      @db=SQLite3::Database.open('adaptive.db')
  end


 def check_line(line)
      if(line=~/deregistered adap_tdagt$/)
         return line
      end
 end

 def store_in_file
       CSV.open('C:/Users/aroraku/Desktop/task8_data.csv','wb') do |csv|
        while line=@f.gets do
            if( check_line(line)!=nil)
                line=~ (/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4}) \[info\]:\s(\S+) /)
                uuid=@db.execute(
                "Select devices.uuid
                 from devices,bas_tokens
                 where bas_tokens.device_id=devices.id AND
                 bas_tokens.token='#{$2}'")
                 uuid=uuid[0]
                 uuid=uuid[0]
              csv << [$1,uuid]
              end
        end
      end
 end
end
```

The unit test program I am able to write successfully is as follows:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/unit'
require './task8'

class TestTask8 < Minitest::Test
  def system

  end
  def test_check_line
     result=Task8.new.check_line("Nov 13 01:46:57 10.232.47.76 qas-adaptiveip-10-232-47-76 2015-11-13 01:46:57 +0000 [info]: qas-296d1fa95fd0ac5a84ea73234c0c48d64f6ea22d has been deregistered adap_tdagt")
     assert_equal result,"Nov 13 01:46:57 10.232.47.76 qas-adaptiveip-10-232-47-76 2015-11-13 01:46:57 +0000 [info]: qas-296d1fa95fd0ac5a84ea73234c0c48d64f6ea22d has been deregistered adap_tdagt",
     'Wrong Output'
  end
  def test_check_line_wrong
     result=Task8.new.check_line("Nov 13 01:46:57 10.232.47.76 qas-adaptiveip-10-232-47-76 2015-11-13 01:46:57 +0000 [info]: qas-296d1fa95fd0ac5a84ea73234c0c48d64f6ea22d has been deregistered")
     assert_nil result
  end
end
```

I am not able to create the test program for store_in_file function. If someone please can help me in this then it would be really great. Also, If I can improve my Ruby program in any way then please let me know.

Comment: "I am not able to create the test program for store_in_file function." -- What, specifically, is keeping you from testing the store_in_file_function?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to understand that unit tests, should not interact with external resources like DB or files, so lets call this tests integration or feature test.

To test the `store_in_file` method you got 2 options:

1. go to the unit test approach, stub the CSV.open return value and test the block execution can be done easily with Rspec mocks.
2. keep it working with actual files, and at the end of the test open 'C:/Users/aroraku/Desktop/task8_data.csv' and validate it's content like this

   ```
     file.each_line do |line|
       line.split(",").each do |item|
         assert...
        end
     end
   ```